# In FoilTeX, with sans serif font, \emph gives serif font

Tags: sans-serif, emphasis

I'm using the foils class. I'd like all the text to be serif, so I added 
`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}`
to the preamble. However, when I use `\emph{}`, it displays italicised SANS serif!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{foils}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\begin{document}
\foilhead{Test slide}
This word is \emph{emphasized}.
\end{document}
```

Help greatly appreciated! -Lu

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Where can `foils` be found?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The class is quite old and has not so many features. Are you really sure you want to use it?

Comment: I will reconsider whether I ought to use it. I like the featurelessness and simplicity, but no doubt there are more elegant means to these ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fltfonts.def` file contains an instruction equivalent to

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{fcmr}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * fcmss/m/sl}{}
```

which basically means: if the family is `fcmr` and the requested fonts shape is slanted, use the slanted font from the `fcmss` family. The same file also changes `\em` to select `\slshape` rather than `\itshape`.

You get the standard behavior by reinstating the usual definition of `\em`:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{foils}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{\@nomath\em \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
     \upshape \else \itshape \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foilhead{Test slide}

This word is \emph{emphasized}.
\end{document}
```

But this class is quite old and has few features compared to more modern ones like `beamer` or `powerdot`.